# Lyrics of "Keep it up" by Snap?

Tags: lyrics

I've been searching up and down for the lyrics of this song but couldn't find it anywhere!

Sad thing is I don't understand a single line of it :(

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lhr1tjJSeFk

Comment: Definitely the wrong one - I'm struggling too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FINALLY here are the lyrics to the song. Taken from the booklet on the Japanese version of  Snap's "The madman's return - 3rd Edition" CD album.

> Like a monsoon, typhoon stormin' in the worst way
>   Hear to say no play, hear what I say?
>   Not going out 'cause I got it goin' on
>   Intense, scary like a fog horn
>   Strong renegade, cannot be slaved
>   You want to rat me
>   A is my grade
>   Move to groove to manipulate a pro
>   You takin' 'em out
>   With a rock hard body blow
>   With a rock hard body blow
>   With a rock hard body blow
>   With a rock hard body blow
>
> Quick on the draw
>   Shoot for the jaw
>   Cold to the bone
>   Rebel stand tall
>   Ask for nothing
>   Earn what I'm giving
>   Take what I want
>   Large I'm living
>   Ring the bell
>   Feel the vibrations
>   Straight for the kill
>   Professed stimulation
>   Calculation for the situation at the end
>   It's called a conviction
>
> Keep it up, keep it up, keep it up,
>   Yea
>   Keep it up, keep it up, keep it up,
>   Ooo
>
> Make you sweat, threat
>   Like a hydroid, piss on your mom,
>   like you were Android
>   Landlord will fight us
>   Others are my tenants
>   I'm hard, I said it, You know that I meant it
>   I control your soul, Cole, because adrenalin
>   Feels good like a climax
>   Pull into your motion, oh cliche
>   Come out boomin' is what I say
>   That’s what I say
>
> Keep it up, keep it up, keep it up,
>   Yea
>   Keep it up, keep it up, keep it up,
>   Ooo
>   Keep it up

Answer (score -1):

I simply Googled Snap - Keep It Up lyrics and found this:  https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Snap-14/Keep-It-Up

Comment: It doesn't look like OP's song. There might be a "Rocky" version of the song...

Comment: Yeah I found that one too, but I don't think it's the right one